# C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, linux, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd rewritten a simple C++ program using `unix` as a variable name. But the program compilation failed.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
        int unix = 1;
        return 0;
}
```

After searching a lot on the internet I got to this website which helped me by saying that `unix` is predefined macro equal to `1`.

I want to know list of all such predefined macros.

Comment: Predefined macro in **lower-case** ? Seems weird :o

Comment: Rather, if you're using an IDE, you may set the color of displayed macro as an easily identifiable one. Visual studio has it.

Answer (score 24):

You can list all the predefined macros by using the GNU preprocessor `cpp` as:

```
cpp -dM file.cpp
```

Also note that macros such as `unix`, `linux` are non standard and you can disable them by using the `-ansi` compilation flag as:

```
g++ -ansi file.cpp
```

And you can use the `-ansi` flag with `cpp` also to get the list of all standard predefined macros:

```
cpp -dM -ansi file.cpp
```

Answer (score 4):

touch mysymdef.h; g++ -dM mysymdef.h
It will generate a file mysymdef.h.gch which will have all predefined symbols/macros for you system. File is binary but with some edit it will work out.

for details refer to

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such a list as you are asking for that's available across every potential platform. You may want to see [Pre-defined macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/) for more information. The 'gcc -dM' will work on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ uname 
Linux

$ cpp -dM <<<'' | grep unix
#define __unix__ 1
#define __unix 1
#define unix 1
```